# How to make a call in fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

This is my code for Hotline fragment. The problem is it cannot do a call. there was an error prompting see below:

> Error: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.julieridon.kabitenyo, PID: 16445
>       java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.CALL dat=tel:xxx
>   cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity } from
>   ProcessRecord{4bd5fc6 16445:com.example.julieridon.kabitenyo/u0a0}
>   (pid=16445, uid=10000) with revoked permission
>   android.permission.CALL_PHONE
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2021)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1967)
>           at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityManager.java:4822)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1619)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4621)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:767)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4579)
>           at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:754)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4940)
>           at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4908)
>           at com.example.julieridon.kabitenyo.HotlinesActivity$1.onClick(HotlinesActivity.java:31)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6935)
>           at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12742)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26211)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)

Code for Hotline Fragment:

```
public class HotlinesActivity extends Fragment {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_hotlines, container, false);
    Button btnFragments = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.call);
    btnFragments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "123"));
            getActivity().startActivity(callIntent);
        }
    });
return view;
}
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#DialPhone

Answer (score 0):

For call you need to add CALL_PHONE permission in AndroidManifest.xml like

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Android has two kind of permission one is normal one and other one is **DANGEROUS** permission.
In Android 5.1.1 and below all kind of permissions are granted automatically.But in Android 5.1.1 above we will need to ask user for granting permission if the permission is of **DANGEROUS** type. so you can ask CALL permission like

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "123"));
        getActivity().startActivity(callIntent);
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                CALL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

And you can check the grant request result with **onRequestPermissionsResult** method like

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == CALL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Complete Code May look like**

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final int CALL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_hotlines, container, false);
        Button btnFragments = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.call);
        btnFragments.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                call();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    void call() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + "123"));
            getActivity().startActivity(callIntent);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    CALL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == CALL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir another question, how about making multiple button for different calls? it is possible? or not?

Comment: use this, pass different number on different press 
void call(String phoneNumber) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber));
            getActivity().startActivity(callIntent);
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                    CALL_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }